# Python Webscraping dynamic website with load more buttons

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to get all the doctor-information from this website:
https://www.medicus-online.at/aek/dist/medicus-suche

Its build is really uncomfortable. I know how I can show all doctors at once (go to "Alle Bezirke", choose a random value, then choose "Alle Bezirke" again)
But how do I do it automatically with BeautifulSoup or SELENIUM so I can get ALL The doctors, with expanded (load more) html fields so I can also see the appointment schedules, etc.?

My goal is to bring them into a CSV-file

I tried it with SELENIUM but most of the time I didn't know how to route through the "BEZIRKE" or how to show "ALL BEZIRKE" with expanded information

Answer (score 0):

**Refer the below working code:** Explanation can be found in the comments in code. Basically it will ***Go to "Alle Bezirke" --> choose the first dropdown value --> then choose "Alle Bezirke" again***

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.medicus-online.at/aek/dist/medicus-suche')
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
# below like will click on dropdown down arrow
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@id='bezirk-custom-select']//span)[1]"))).click()
# below like will click on dropdown value "Bezirk Bludenz"
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@id='bezirk-custom-select']//span)[3]"))).click()
time.sleep(10)
# below like will click on dropdown down arrow
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@id='bezirk-custom-select']//span)[1]"))).click()
# below like will click on dropdown value "Alle Bezirke"
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@id='bezirk-custom-select']//span)[2]"))))
time.sleep(60)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I also managed to get something similar but I like yours too + the comments are great to understand.

However I still don't know how I get the information about EVER doctor like Name, number, Appointment Times, Specialities on the "LOAD MORE" / "MEHR ANZEIGEN" buttons. How do I gather them so I can turn it into a csv-database